# Is it beneficial to train 1 object detector for N classes vs N object detectors each for a different class?

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection

I always wondered if training an object detector to recognize (let's say), dogs and cats performs better or worse than training 2 object detectors, one for cats only and one for dogs only.

Would this affect accuracy in any way? Are there scenarios where this approach would make sense ?